# Print foreign key value in template without doing a query

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a query that I do in my view to get a bunch of team stat objects...

```py
    team_stats = NCAABTeamStats.objects.filter(
            name__name__in=teams_playing).order_by(sort)
```

One of the fields 'name' is a foreign key. I pass team_stats to my template to display the data in a chart via a 'for loop'.

```py
    {% for team in team_stats %}
       <tr>
          <td>
              {{ team.name }}
          </td>
       </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

So in my template, for every object in team_stats it is doing a query when it prints    {{ team.name }} and it really slows things down, especially when there are 50-100 teams.

My question is, is there a way to print 'team.name' without it doing a query every time?

Comment: Can you please post your model definitions i.e. `NCAABTeamStats` and `Name` models.

Comment: if it is a foreignkey you can do something like this `team_stats=NCAABTeamStats.objects.select_related('name').filter(name__name__in=teams_playing).order_by(sort)`

Comment: @amadousow That is exactly what I was looking for. Worked like a charm, thanks so much! If you want to put it as the answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it is a foreignkey you can do something like this

```
team_stats=NCAABTeamStats.objects.select_related('name').filter(name__name__in=teams_playing).order_by(sort)
```

you can learn more on select_related [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-related)

if it is a manytomany field you can do something like this

```
team_stats=NCAABTeamStats.objects.prefetch_related('name').filter(name__name__in=teams_playing).order_by(sort)
```

you can learn more on prefetch_related [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)